# How to programmatically change pristine property in angular 2 form without ng-model

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I'm new in Angular 2 framework. I appreciate any help.

I have usual component in angular 2:

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

export class TestComponent {
    public values = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
}
```

Then I'm injecting `FormBuilder` into the constructor function:

```
@Inject(FormBuilder) public fb
```

HTML contain next markup:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="formData.title" type="text" class="form-control" ngControl="title">
```

Title and description works great. 
But I've added bootstrap dropdown and **it has no any form element**.

```
<div *ngFor="#value of values" (click)="onValueChanged(value)" class="dropdown-item">{{value}}</div>
```

So, the problem is that html markup doesn't contain any model.
The way I tried to solve this issue is to create function `onValueChanged`

```
 onValueChanged(value){
    this.formData.controls.value.updateValue(value);
    this.formData.value = value;
    console.log(this.formData.pristine) //Still true :(
}
```

Both of these line are not working, because `this.formData.pristine` is not changes after dropdown is changed.

For now I'm thinking how to update `FormBuilder`, it would be fine to have some methods, for example `this.fb.update()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove `pristine` status using

```
this.formData.controls.value.markAsDirty();
```

The current possibilities are quite limited. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933

Comment: If this answers your question please accept the answer to indicate the problem is solved. If you want to wait for alternative answers you don't need to accept it though. You can also make another answer the accepted answer at any time.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how to do the same in template driven forms? If I have the form declared like `#myForm="ngForm" ` and accessing `myForm.form.controls.value` in a function  gives `undefined` !

Comment: You also need `@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;` to be able to access the form from the components code. `myForm` won't be set when the constuctor is executed. Besides that, you can use `this.myForm.get('controlName')....`